# Mobile + web application - project start

Tags: android, firebase, nativescript

I was presented with a project of an application that would be mobile and web-based. The idea is to generate an app for android, ios + web with just one code. It is an application where users can register and add items to various items. This would happen via a mobile and web application + via a web base management panel. Based on a common base in the sense that the mobile and web applications use the same base.

I am a PHP, MySQL developer, JavaScript is not terrible to me, and most of my professional life I have been writing e-shops, CMS-based websites and other scripts that make life easier.

Now I would like to bite this topic in a way that is convenient for me, looking at what I can do. I heard about GCP with a FireBase database which provides some pretty cool features. I am trying to harness FireBase under PHP, but I don't know if that is the right way. I've also heard of NativeScript which feels nice and allows you to write apps natively for Android and iOS. But is it on the web?

Can you advise on which technologies to enter? How to do it?

Comment: You could start researching hybrid mobile app development like Ionic, Angular, React, Node.js, etc

Comment: You may also check flutter approach for mobile (android, ios) and web